# Can square root of a normal operator be normal too ??

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Suppose $T$ is normal on a complex inner product space, I have proved that $T$ has a square root $S$. Can it be normal too ?

Comment: If $T$ is the identity map...

Answer (score 5):

Certainly.  In the event that $T$ is the identity operator, this is trivially true since $T$ is its own square root. Perhaps less trivially, if $T$ is a scaling operator, then its square root is well-defined and normal.

However, this is not necessarily the case.  Consider, as a counter-example $T = 0\in \mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$, with square root
$$
S = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We may note, on the other hand, that any finite-dimensional normal operator has a normal square root.  Indeed, if $T$ is normal, then
$$
T = UDU^*
$$
For some unitary $U$ and diagonal $D$.  $S = UD^{1/2}U^*$ is a normal matrix satisfying $S^2 = T$.