# $T^2$ normal operator means that $T$ is normal operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, normal-operator

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ linear transformation, $V=\mathbb{C}$

Is that true that if $T^2$ is normal operator so $T$?

I know that if $T$ is normal so $T^2$ is normal but I have no idea how to think on the opposite direction.

Comment: Not necessarily. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/543591/81360) for instance

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I still didn't understand how I can contradict it

Comment: If you take 
$$
T = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},
$$
then $T^2$ is normal but $T$ is not.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take
$$
T = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},
$$
then $T^2$ is normal but $T$ is not.